# How to check a string if a string has only alphabetical characters in C++

Tags: c++, string, boolean

I'm writing a program for an assignment. Part of it is I need to validate a certain string so it only contains alphabetical characters but I can't figure it out.
This was a test code I used to attempt to write a validator.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool isValidName(string str);
string str[20];

main() {
  cout << "enter name\n ";
  getline(cin, str[1]);
  isValidName(str[1]);
  cout << isValidName << endl;
  system("pause");
}

bool isValidName(string str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)str.length(); i++) {
    if (!isalpha(str[i])) {
      return false;
      break;
    }
    return true;
    break;
  }
}
```

It doesn't matter what kind of character I put it, it will always return 1 :o(

(Thanks to Paul Rooney for fixing the indentation)

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this program? How does the actual results differ from what you want?

Comment: You should also fix the indentation of your code. Ever line should have an extra four spaces at the beginning in addition to whatever spaces you need for indenting. When you copy and paste your code, you can highlight it and push Ctrl-K to insert these extra spaces automatically.

Comment: Hint: `string str[20]` is not a twenty character string, it's an array of twenty strings. Arrays are also zero indexed, so `str[0]` is the first entry.

Comment: Your `break`s are superfluous. They come after return statements. Also consider if you want to return true after you check that only the first character `isalpha`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! @tadman I put str[20] because I wanted an array of strings, but I'm testing the validation on only one.

Comment: @Paul you're right about the breaks. Thanks for that!

Comment: If you're using C++ one of the first things to come to grips with is using `std::vector` for all things. It's also best to avoid `using namespace std` since that can cause collisions and rampant confusion over where the various methods originate. Typing in `std::` all the time might seem needlessly verbose, but it's actually something that you get used to where it lends clarity as to what's going on.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code has two `break` statements that aren't needed. The `return` statements that come immediately before them will return from the function; no need to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems was you were not printing the return of the function, you were printing the the function variable.
    cout << isValidName << endl; //wrong

you were also already making returning in the first character check, I hope the code below can help you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
bool isValidName(string str);
string str;

main(){
    cout << "enter name\n ";
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << isValidName(str) << endl;
}

bool isValidName(string str) {
    for(int i=0;i<(int)str.length();i++) {
        if (!isalpha(str[i])) {
            return false;     
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

fixed thanks to rooney

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Thanks for choosing my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of writing your validation proc would be:

```
bool isValidName(const std::string& str) 
{
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isalpha);
}
```

In your function:

```
bool isValidName(string str) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<(int)str.length();i++) 
    {
        if (!isalpha(str[i])) 
        {
            return false;
            break;               // breaking here is useless, you've already returned.
        }
        return true;            // this is not in the right spot.  you return true
                                // if the first character is alpha !!
    }

    return true;               // <-- should be here.
}
```

Proper indentation makes these errors easy to spot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This, in addition to the other answer, helped me out. I also learned I really have to work on my indentation ( both in my code and when posting a question because the indentations in the post aren't the same as in my code)

Comment: Please see the c++ way of doing the same thing, that makes your validation a one-liner.

Comment: Better put the STL solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant solution is to use regular expressions to validate your input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool isValidName(const std::string& str)
{
    if (std::regex_match(str, std::regex("[[:alpha:]]*")))
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("aaASd");
    std::cout << isValidName(s) << std::endl;
    std::string s1("ss23d");
    std::cout << isValidName(s1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```